# When radio button is checked redirect to second page and hide certain html element in the second page by checking if radio button was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, local-storage

Here is my first page data in html

```
<div class="edu">
    <input type="radio" name="edu" class="ug" value="ug" checked="checked">
    <label class="radio-label">Undergraduate</label>
    <input type="radio" name="edu" value="pg" class="pg">
    <label class="radio-label">Postgraduate</label>
    <input type="radio" name="edu" value="cu" class="cu">
    <label class="radio-label">Continuing Education</label>
</div>
```

Here is my second page content:

```
<div class="display"> 
sample text 
</div>
```

When the client check the "continuing education" radio button from the first page then the second page will be redirected/opened in a new window/new tab. An in second page I want to check if the "continuing education" button was clicked in the first page. If, then hide the  ".display" div in the second page.

I want to use Jquery, and any other things in addition if needed. 
Please guide me as I am new. Thanks.

Comment: where's your second page html??

Comment: Means you eant to load second,html which contains the second div? Or the first page contain the second div?

Comment: @SandipanGuha in my second page i have the following code <div class="second_div">Second div</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load jQuery from here at top of both first and second html file:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Add this jQuery code at the bottom of the first page:

```
 <script> 
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".cu").on("click", function(){  
      localStorage.setItem("cu","clicked");
      //var key = localStorage.key(0); 
      //alert(key);
      window.open('second.html', '_blank'); 
    });
    });
</script>
```

Then at the bottom of the second html page add this code. Which will check if localStorage value was set to "cu" thorough which you can understand "continuing education" were clicked or not. If, then it will hide the *".display"* div.

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   if(localStorage.key(0) == "cu")
    {
     //$(".display").fadeOut(500) ;
      $(".display").hide(500) ;
     //alert(localStorage.key(0));
     localStorage.clear();
     localStorage.removeItem("cu");
    }
  });  
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick respone.
 i already tried using the above code. it was not working as expected . in j query , is that possible to use ajax method. kindly pls suggest.

Comment: Did you made a second.html page in your directory? And added the display div? I made it.. Use firefox as your browser.

Comment: yes buddy i tired the same because the chrome was not support load it require localhost so i tried in firefox :(

Comment: so that was the reason i asked is there any way to use ajax method

Comment: This <div class="second_div">Second div</div>
  line from second page instead of creating entire page i just put the relevant line so when the user click continuing education from the first page in the second page this div will hide

Comment: I can not under stand your speech you want to hide the second page. But when did you show it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91971/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-ashik).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92007/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-ashik).